# Iterate over list of strings in terraform/terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Is there a way to iterate over list of strings in a clean way?
This is my data structure:

```
    iam_access = {
        external_iam_users = {
          "environment1" = {
            iam_users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
          },
        "environment2" = {
            iam_users = ["user4", "user5"]
          },
    }
```

I created a locals as follows:

```
locals {
  user_access = merge([
    for external_iam_users in var.iam_access: {
      for key,iam_users in external_iam_users : "${key}" => {
        for key1,users in iam_users : "${key1}" => {
          users = users
        }
      }
    }
  ]...)
}
```

and want to use for attachment:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  for_each = {
    for key, value in local.user_access :
    key => value
    if length(value.iam_users.users) > 0
  }

  user       = each.value.iam_users.users[0]
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I have `user = each.value.iam_users.users[0]`, which takes first element from users list, that is "user1" and "user4". How can I write the code so that I will have something like `user = each.value.iam_users.users[x]`, where `x` is a value from 0 to length of the list, so I will cover all the possbile users.

Comment: you just want a unique list of all users regardless of environment to iterate over in a foreach ?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this we merely require a `set(string)` containing all of the nested users for the resource to iterate through. The first step is to use the `flatten([[[...]]])` of nested lists algorithm instead of `merge` the nested `map` and `object`:

```
# modifying your code in the question
user_access = flatten([
  for external_iam_users in local.iam_access : [
    for key, iam_users in external_iam_users : [
      for key1, users in iam_users : [users]
    ]
  ]
])

# more optimal as suggested in comment
user_access = flatten([for env_name, env_data in local.iam_access.external_iam_users : env_data.iam_users])
```

now `local.user_access` for your example is assigned:

```
iam_users = [
  "user1",
  "user2",
  "user3",
  "user4",
  "user5",
]
```

which is exactly what is desired because now we update the resource like:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  for_each = local.user_access

  user       = each.value
  ...
}
```

and the objective is achieved.

Comment: This could even be simplified to a single for loop `flatten([for env_name, env_data in local.iam_access.external_iam_users : env_data.iam_users])`